# Alternate to CROSS Join in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have situation wherein I need to combine two datasets. Here are those

```
-- Dataset 1
Date         Count
2014-12-01      5
2014-11-01      3

-- Dataset 2
Date          Col1     Col2     Col3
2014-12-05    cv11     cv12     cv13
2014-12-01    cv21     cv22     cv23
2014-11-30    cv31     cv32     cv33
2014-11-01    cv41     cv42     cv43
2014-10-15    cv51     cv52     cv53
```

Now, what I need to do is place the count in dataset where if the date matches in both the sets, then the corresponding count value will be taken. Otherwise, the value which is contained by the lower date needs to be generated (I am really sorry if I am not able to phrase the question correctly. Please feel free to edit to make it clearer)

Essentially, here is the output which I am looking for. If you see, till `2014-12-01`, the count was 3 and hence all dates which are available in our dataset2, will generate count as 3 and all dates post `2014-12-01` will generate a value of 5 in the count column.

```
-- Output
Date          Col1     Col2     Col3   Count
2014-12-05    cv11     cv12     cv13      5
2014-12-01    cv21     cv22     cv23      5
2014-11-30    cv31     cv32     cv33      3
2014-11-01    cv41     cv42     cv43      3
2014-10-15    cv51     cv52     cv53      3
```

I was trying to do the same using `CROSS` join, but that is causing my job to take hours as both the datasets are pretty large in size. Dataset1(~500K) and Dataset2(~5Million).

Because, both the datasets are pretty bulky, CROSS isn't sufficing the case.

Is there anything else which can be done?

Comment: CROSS is most likely the wrong thing to do here. Cross product is generating 500k * 5 million = 2.5 trillion records. So, don't do that. Are there any guarantees in your dataset 1 that can be leveraged? Such as, the counts are generated on the first of every month. Or is it completely arbitrary?

Comment: Also, how do you have 500k records in DS1? If your only two columns are date and count, it will take you 1400 years to generate 500k rows if you generate 1 row per day. I'm assuming you left something out of the example assuming WLOG

Comment: Good question with dataset1. We are not generating that. Its a count file brought from another system. I was thinking to generate all the dates in my dataset1 in the source system and then bring in Hadoop.

Comment: One solution might be to write a UDF that loads Dataset into memory from Distributed Cache and tolook up the count value for each record Dataset 2 by calling the UDF. not great, but with 500K records of this size it should work.